# Modelado en Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Buenas tardes, saben como puedo visualizar el modelo lógico y/o físico en Workbench??, He usado anteriormente Erwin y se podía visualizar ambos, pero ahora me piden en Workbench y no logro encontrar esa opción de cambiar de vistas

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que te refieres a como ver el diagrama de la base de datos. En MySQL Workbench puedes hacer los 2 procesos. De **diagrama a tabla** y de **tabla a diagrama**. Entiendo que tienes una serie de tablas y quieres extraer el diagrama a partir de estas.

Entonces el proceso es:

Vas al **menu superir** y buscas la opcion **Database** despues seleccionas **Reverse Engineer** aquí te aparecerá una ventana con una serie de pasos, sigues todos los pasos que te pida. Al finalizar tendrás el diagrama de la base de datos.

Para ir desde el diagrama hacia las tablas seleciona la opcion **Fordward Engineer**.